# Я написал dll на c, а она не работает, пишет нет точки входа

Tags: c, dll, компиляция, dllimport

Я решил попробовать написать свою dll, которая при подключении просто выводит диалоговое окно

Вот исходный код:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib");
    
    BOOL WINAPI DLLMain(HANDLE hDLL, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
        switch (dwReason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            MessageBox(NULL, "Hi, from DLL!", "BABYDLL", MB_ICONASTERISK | MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Далее я скомпилировал dll с помощью команды:

cl /D_USERDLL /D_WINDLL babydll.c /link /DLL /OUT:babydll.dll

Вывод этой команды:

```
babydll.c
babydll.c(2): warning C4081: требуется "newline"; обнаружен ";"
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.37.32822.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:babydll.exe
/DLL
/OUT:babydll.dll
babydll.obj
```

И когда я пытаюсь запустить dll с помощью:

rundll32 babydll.dll,.text

Я вижу вот такое окно[image: После запуска rundll32]

Не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться в чём тут проблема?

Comment: С `rundll32`, признаюсь честно, не работал, но мне казалось, что в строке вызова `rundll32` указывается библиотека и функция, но функция-то у вас не указана.

Comment: Функция указана - `.text`, только ее нет в библиотеке. А еще в `DLLMain` нельзя вызывать `MessageBox`.

Comment: @user7860670 Это скорее сегмент, чем имя функции, нет?

Comment: @Harry Наверное, но тут оно указано в качестве имени функции для `rundll32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте вызываемую функцию.

Ну, например:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void _cdecl Test()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hi, from DLL!", "BABYDLL", MB_ICONASTERISK | MB_OK);
}
```

Компилируйте все точно так же, но вызывайте как

```
rundll32 babydll.dll Test
```

P.S. Но вообще-то формально правильный прототип вызываемых функций

```
void CALLBACK EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

С `Test` это я не то чтобы погорячился :), но сделал минимальный работающий пример, образно говоря. Если надо работать всерьез, то делайте входные точки по правилам...

P.P.S. И уберите вы эту точку с запятой в строке прагмы, она там ни к чему.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало!